# ExecuteUpdate() exception after changing table name

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, phpmyadmin

I am modifying a Java web application, that was previously written (by someone else), which uses JDBC. The database was created using PHPMyAdmin. During the process, I needed to rename one of the tables. I replaced in the code the old name with the right one but now the app seems to be searching for the old table when I try to insert new records.

This is the exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.reclamation' doesn't exist
```

`reclamation` is the old name of the table.

This is my code:

```
public class ServletUserEnquiryForm extends HttpServlet{
  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{

    super.init(config);
  }

  /**Process the HTTP Get request*/
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                             throws ServletException, IOException{

    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String shop = request.getParameter("shop");
    System.out.println(shop);
    String name = request.getParameter("names");
    System.out.println(name);
    String  tell = request.getParameter("tell");
    String stoke = request.getParameter("stoke");
    String model = request.getParameter("model");
    String barcod = request.getParameter("barkod");
    String bon = request.getParameter("bon");
    String fack = request.getParameter("fack");
    if(fack.equals("")){
    fack = "0";
    }
    String comentar = request.getParameter("comentar");
    String reasonable = request.getParameter("reasonable");
    if(reasonable == "yes")
    {
    reasonable = "yes";
    }
    else
    {
    reasonable = "no";
    }

    String in_store = request.getParameter("in_store");
    if(in_store == "yes")
    {
    in_store = "yes";
    }
    else 
    {
    in_store = "no";
    }

    String satisfaction = request.getParameter("satisfaction");
    if(satisfaction == "zamqna")
    {
    satisfaction = "Замяна";
    }
    else 
    if(satisfaction == "remont")
    {
        satisfaction = "Ремонт";
    }
    else
        if(satisfaction == "namalenie")
        {
            satisfaction = "Намаление";
        }
        else
            if(satisfaction == "return")
            {
                satisfaction = "Връщане на сума";
            }
    //String okomplektovka = request.getParameter("okomplektovka");

    String type_return = request.getParameter("type_return");
    if(type_return == "sum")
    {
    type_return = "sum";
    }
    else
    if(type_return == "bank")
    {
        type_return = "bank";
    }
    else
        type_return = "";

    String sum = request.getParameter("sum");
    if(sum == "")
    {
    sum = "0.00";
    }

    String iban = request.getParameter("iban");
    if(iban =="")
    {
    iban = "N/A";
    }
    String servis = request.getParameter("servis");

    if(reasonable != null && in_store != null && satisfaction != null && type_return != null)
    {
    try {
        Connection con = dbSQL.getConnection();
        String tableName = "shop_"+shop;
        String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (name,tel,product_type,model,genkod,receipts,invoice,description,reasonable,in_store,satisfaction,type_return,sum,iban,shop,data_in,servis)" + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, sysdate(), ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, tell);
        ps.setString(3, stoke);
        ps.setString(4, model);
        ps.setString(5, barcod);
        ps.setString(6, bon);
        ps.setString(7, fack);
        ps.setString(8, comentar);
        ps.setString(9, reasonable);
        ps.setString(10, in_store);
        ps.setString(11, satisfaction);
        ps.setString(12, type_return);
        ps.setString(13, sum);
        ps.setString(14, iban);
        ps.setString(15, shop);
        ps.setString(16, servis);
        ps.executeUpdate();
      ps.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    finally {


      }

    }
  }

}
```

Works fine until it gets to `ps.executeUpdate()` and I cannot see where seems to be the problem.

This is the definition of `dbSQL`:

```
public class dbSQL {

private static final String DB_HOST ="192.168.15.26";
private static final String DB_USER = "root";
private static final String DB_PASS = "passs";
private static final String DB_NAME = "test?characterEncoding=UTF-8";

private static final String useDB = "mysql";


public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {

Connection conn = null;
    try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + DB_HOST + ":3306/" + DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
   }

}
```

Comment: OT: Really this comparison if(reasonable == "yes") works for you?

Comment: Is there anyting in your DB which reference the old table name, such a trigger?

Comment: SHOW TRIGGERS doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Where is "tableName" defined?
Your SQLExceptions claimes, that this tabel does not exist, so check the definition of "tableName" and set it to the correct name of the table.

Comment: I want to use the same code with few identical tables (but containing different information) and that's why I have
    String tableName = "shop_"+shop;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (name,tel...";
When debugging I see that the query looks right. It points to the right table.